# « Livres d'amour bêtes » : de quels livres s'agit-il ?

Tags: littérature

Dans *Les Misérables* lorsque Hugo parle de « La Thénardier », il dit qu'elle lit des « livres d'amour bêtes ».

De quels livres Hugo parle-t-il ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il s'agit de ce que l'on appelle aussi des "*romans à l'eau de rose*" ou encore "*romans de gare*".
C'est à dire encore d'une littérature facile et simpliste qui se lit facilement et rapidement.